# Customized Datagrid in C# XAML not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Well I have this `DataGrid` in my `XAML`:

```xml
<DataGrid Width="250" Height="250" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Alter" Width="50"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```cs
private readonly MyPersonContext db = new MyPersonContext();

public MyViewModel()
{
    personList = db.Persons.ToList();
}

private List<Person> personList;
public List<Person> PersonList
{
    get => personList;
    set { 
        personList = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(PersonList));
    }
}
```

The problem is that my customized DataGrid is shown but after it all of the database content is shown

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false on the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Width="250" Height="250" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="200"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Alter" Width="50"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The default value is `true` so the `DataGrid` will generate all columns unless its turned off.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand the problem statement correctly, you are saying all the DB contents are shown - does that mean all the columns are displayed or all the rows, if rows, isn't that the intent?

One thing which I would like to correct in the code block is, in the constructor, you are initializing the private member of personlist, try writing this instead -

`public MyViewModel() { PersonList = db.Persons.ToList(); }`

Comment: This won't make any difference.